# How to check the employee id is exist in attendance table?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm trying to find the employee in attendance table with in the specific date if the employee id is not exist on that date so it should be mark it as ('Absent')

please help me to solve it.

```
 $dateof = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['attdateof']));
    $allemp = mysql_query("SELECT empid FROM `attendance` WHERE todaydate = '2016-03-17'"); 
    if(mysql_num_rows($allemp) > 0)
    {
        $emp_from_detail = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `empdetail`");
    (int)$empdetailid = array();
            while($emp = mysql_fetch_array($emp_from_detail))
            {
                $empdetailid[] = $emp[0];   
            }
        (int)$id_in_att = array();
            while($e = mysql_fetch_array($allemp))
            {
                $id_in_att = $e[0];
            }   
        for($i = 0; $i <= mysql_num_rows($emp_from_detail); $i++)
        {

            if($empdetailid[$i] != $id_in_att[$i])
                {
                    $markappcent = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `attendance`(`id`,`empid`, `empstatus`, `todaydate`) VALUES ('','".$empdetailid[$i]."','Absent','".$_POST['attdateof']."')");
                    if($markappcent)
                    {echo"<script>alert('Marked Successfully. ".$empdetailid[$i]."');</script>";}
                    else
                    {echo"<script>alert('Try Again ".$empdetailid[$i]."');</script>";}
                }

        }

    } 
    else
                    {echo"<script>alert('Data not found');</script>";}
```

Comment: Give us your table structure...

Comment: you are using a deprecated api to connect to mysql (mysql_*) that have been removed in php7. Also your code is open to SQL Injections!

Comment: to put it simple, you want to insert all employees from `empdetail` with `Absent` if they are not already in `attendance` with `todaydate = yourdate` ?

Comment: Yes exactly want this...Alex Andrei

Answer (score 1):

well, this could be solved via one query. something like this:

```
INSERT INTO attendance
SELECT NULL as id, empdetail.id as empid, 'Absent' as empstatus, '2016-03-17' as empdate 
FROM empdetail WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT empid 
    FROM attendance 
    WHERE todaydate = '2016-03-17'
)
```

**explanation of query:**
first there is selected all from attendance table, where date is today.
then it is selected all from empdetail table, where id of employee is not in set of previously selected people (which was there) and result of that select is inserted into attendance table..

it could be also done by joins instead of subquery, but it think this is more clear (just my opinion).

as mentioned in comments: beware the sql injection.

hope the query helps..

Comment: dear sir i want to get all employee ids which are not exist in attendance table on specific date. can you please tel me the query of it.?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have solved my problem by this query

```
Select * from `empdetail` e left join `attendance` a on e.id = a.empid and a.todaydate = '2016-04-21' where empstatus is null
```

Answer (score 0):

its not exact ans but you have to do something like this

have to loop the whole emp id and check in_array to attendance table id exists or not .if exists means just echo its else mark him as absent

hope it help  you
**in_array** function

```
for($i = 0; $i <= mysql_num_rows($emp_from_detail); $i++)
        {

            if(in_array($empdetailid[$i],$id_in_att)
                {

                        echo "id exists ".;
                }
                else
                {



                    $markappcent = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `attendance`(`id`,`empid`, `empstatus`, `todaydate`) VALUES ('','".$empdetailid[$i]."','Absent','".$_POST['attdateof']."')");
                    if($markappcent)
                    {echo"<script>alert('Marked Successfully. ".$empdetailid[$i]."');</script>";}
                    else
                    {echo"<script>alert('Try Again ".$empdetailid[$i]."');</script>";}

                }

        }
```